# Datagridview with Checkbox column dont keep unchecked value C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a Winform with a datagridview on it, this datagridview has a checkbox column.

I fill the datagridview with data fron a datatable and it does perfectly right, and the checkbox column turns checked with the values from the datatable that indicates that record is valid and unchecked with the values that indicates that record is invalid.

If I uncheck a checked row works fine, the checked cell turns unchecked, but the problem begins when I try to uncheck 2 or more rows, exactly when I try to uncheck the second row, the firstone (the one that I uncheck previously) suddenly turns checked while the second turns unchecked, and so on.

When I try to uncheck the thrid row it turns unchecked, but the second row suddenlu turns checked.

What can I do, Which property of the Datagridview have to change in order to enable multiple uncheckings

Comment: You will need to provide some code - there is nothing special required to make this work. Somewhere your code is reverting the state of the boolean

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your uncheckings might not be saving, are you doing a post back every time you un-check? And if so, do you have code that saves the changes every time you uncheck, because if you uncheck without saving and then uncheck another, it may be refreshing the data and since the first uncheck was never saved, it appears as checked again.